# Hitting iOS assertion when dismissing ViewController containing WKWebView displaying a PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, webkit, assertion

I'm hitting an iOS assertion when dismissing a `UIViewController`.  The `UIViewController` has a `UIView`, to which I've added a `WKWebView`.  Into that `WKWebView` I've loaded a PDF file.  The PDF displays and functions fine.  When I *dismiss* the window, Xcode reports an assertion:

```
-[PDFExtensionTopView _accessibilityUnregisterRemoteView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If I have my `All Objective-C Exceptions` breakpoint on, execution is stopped.  I can continue, but this is rather disruptive.  Users never see any issue, so this is purely a development-time problem.  I work around the issue by disabling breakpoints when using this view, but would prefer to find a real fix.  I'm on Xcode 11.3.1, using ObjC in this class.

I've created a simplified dummy project.  The entire UIViewController's code is below.  It is presented from a simple UIButton that passes nothing to this UIViewController.

Moving the displayPDF method call is in `viewWillAppear`, but no change if in DidAppear, DidLoad, etc.  It isn't related to the specific PDF (I've tried files from multiple sources).

If I use displayHTML (which puts dummy HTML into the webView), I do not experience the problem.

I might just be rusty in ObjC and missing something obvious.  Any thoughts?

```
#import "MyPDFViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface MyPDFViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *pdfContainerView;
- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView *webView;
@end

@implementation MyPDFViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self displayPDF];
}

-(void)displayPDF {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPDFFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.pdfContainerView.frame configuration:[[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init]];
    [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" characterEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    [self.pdfContainerView addSubview:self.webView];
}

-(void)displayHTML {
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body>Hi.</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        //
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you found any solution to this ? one thing notice it's event not calling deinit() method.